# MongoDB inserting new object on update

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am using spring boot MongoRepository, and when trying to update an entity, Mongo inserts a new object instead..
To note, I insert the object in one class [with an instance of the repository], and try to update in another one.

Here is the code:

```
@Autowired
private SMSRepository sRepository;

public ResponseEntity sendSms(){
//do some operations
sRepository.insert(sms);
}
```

then in another class

@Autowired
private SMSRepository sRepository;

```
public String envoi(SMS sms){
// some operations
sRepository.save(sms);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code sample demonstrating your problem ?

Comment: @Veeram see the update

Comment: Are you setting `_id` as part of `SMS` object when you are updating in the second repository call ?

Comment: @Veeram no not really.. I do have an _id field in the sms object but the value is set automatically by mongo itself

Comment: Mongo decides to `save or update` based on the _id value. If value is set it updates else inserts. Here is more about save https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/

Comment: @Veeram I see.. well it is set (for sure).. maybe it is an asynchronous problem